# Assign a vector element to a CStringArray

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am assigning   each of the vector elements to a cstring?

```
    for(int i = 1; i <examplevector.size; i ++)
    {
    CStringArrayexample[i-1] = examplevector[i];
    }
```

There is just a crash here. What could be the reason?

Comment: That shouldn't crash because it shouldn't compile, unless you're using some random vector where `size` is a public data member.

Answer (score 1):

`CStringArray::operator[]` doesn't do bound checking. The most likely reason for a crash is that the array is smaller than the vector in size.

Also, why don't you have any variables? And if you do, why are your variables named the same as the types you use?

If you want to add new elements to the array, use `Add`.

After your edit:

```
CStringArrayexample[i-1] = examplevector[i];
```

You do know that when `i==0`, you're checking element `-1` of the array, right?

Comment: I have no size defined for neither the vector not the CStringArray

Comment: @crr ok, then that's your problem. When you `push_back` in the vector, it increases the size automatically. Use `add` instead of `operator =` for the array.

Comment: yes i also did try doing CStringArrayexample.add(examplevector[i]); it also crashes..

Comment: "add" adds the element in the array at the last index. IS there any other way each elemnt in the vector be added to an array from its index = size -1?